# Ocelot can't find api when deployed to azure app service

Tags: c#, azure, api, azure-web-app-service, ocelot

I created an ocelot gateway that redirects to an api. this works file on localhost but as soon as i deploy the projects to azure app services ocelot stops working. the api still works though.

I already set the DownstreamHostAndPorts to the api app service url and the port to 443. Also the BaseUrl has been set to the gateways app service url.

Deployed not working
[image: Deployed not working]

No problems on localhost
[image: No problems on localhost]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This morning it suddenly worked without changing anything. I think something happened in my cache maybe. I did try to empty it though. Maybe it had to do with the cache in azure.